# npm: command not found centos 7

Tags: node.js, npm, centos7, yum

I am having centos 7 and already installed npm on my machine but when i try npm command its showing me error as

> npm: command not found

```
[vinit@NL577 ~]$ sudo yum install npm
[sudo] password for vinit: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                           | 3.5 kB  00:00:00     
 * base: repos.del.extreme-ix.org
 * epel: repos.del.extreme-ix.org
 * extras: repos.del.extreme-ix.org
 * updates: repos.del.extreme-ix.org
adobe-linux-x86_64                                                                                                             | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
base                                                                                                                           | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                                                           | 4.7 kB  00:00:00     
extras                                                                                                                         | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
google-chrome                                                                                                                  | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
sublime-text                                                                                                                   | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
updates                                                                                                                        | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
Package 1:npm-3.10.10-1.6.16.0.1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do



[vinit@NL577 ~]$ npm
bash: npm: command not found...
```

Comment: `locate npm` or `whereis npm` may help. I'm a bit suspicious of that version number, I'm offered `1.3.6` from `epel` yum repo

Comment: after locate command i found in below location 
 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/

Comment: It seems odd to me to install npm as an individual package. Normally, npm comes bundled with Node. If I was you, I'd use a version manager such as nvm instead. I can post an answer expanding on this if you like.

Comment: @James Hibbard yes it will be helpful

Comment: does the `echo $PATH` contain npm bin folder?

Answer (score 3):

Update the system and install necessary packages

```
yum install curl sudo
```

Install Node.js and npm from the NodeSource repository

We will install Node.js v6 LTS and npm from the NodeSource repository which depends on the EPEL repository being available.

To enable the EPEL repository on your CentOS 7 VPS, issue the following command:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

Once the EPEL repository is enabled run the following command to add the Node.js v6 LTS repository:

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash -
```

Once the NodeSource repository is enabled we can proceed with the Node.js v6 LTS and npm installation:

```
sudo yum install nodejs
```

If it doesn't work, try to uninstall NodeJs and repeat all actions.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum
sudo yum remove -y nodejs
sudo rm /etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource*
sudo yum clean all
```

Answer (score 2):

Update `yum`

```
yum update -y
```

In redhat base OS (tested in centos 7)

```
yum install nodejs npm -y
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems odd to me to install npm as an individual package. Normally, npm comes bundled with Node.

To that end, I would remove any Node versions you have on the PC, then use a version manager to install the desired version of Node (and by default npm).

The version manager I have had the best experience with is nvm. You can find it [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

The TL;DR for installing nvm is:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

But I would encourage you to look at the project on GitHub and read its README. There is also a good tutorial on how to use it [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-multiple-versions-node-nvm/).

Once you have nvm up and running, you can install Node thus:

```
nvm install node # "node" is an alias for the latest version
```

Or to install a specific version of node:

```
nvm install 6.14.4 # or 10.10.0, 8.9.1, etc
```

And then when you run `npm`, the command should be available in your `$PATH`.